# MatAutocomplete with observables

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I'm using Material Autocomplete component.

First letter I type into the input, it works as expected, but it fails next.

That's obviously because I set a new value for `this.filteredUnitName`:

```ts
export class ActionDetailComponent {
    @Input() unitNames: Observable<string[]>;

    filteredUnitNames: Observable<string[]>;

    unitName: FormControl = new FormControl();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.filteredUnitNames = this.unitName.valueChanges
            .startWith(null)
            .do(val => {
                if (val) {
                    this.filteredUnitNames = this.filter(val); // bad line
                }
            });
    }

    filter(val: string): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.unitNames
            .map(response => response.filter(
                option => option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
            ));
    }
```

Here is my template :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Unit name" class="form-control" [formControl]="unitName" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let name of filteredUnitNames | async" [value]="name">
        <span>{{name}}</span>
    </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there another way to make this working properly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with the **[`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)** operator, so change your code to the following:

```ts
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";


ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredUnitNames = this.unitName.valueChanges
    .startWith(null)
    .switchMap(val => {
      return this.filter(val || '')
   })
}

filter(val: string): string[] {
  return this.unitNames
    .map(response => response.filter(option => { 
       return option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
    }));
}
```

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/yb4NeYTbGkwHay15R8CW?p=preview

Comment: It throws me this error : "Property flatMap does not exist on type Observable<any>" :/

Comment: Yeah, you need to import it, but I changed to `switchMap`, it's better in this case. So check the updated answer, which includes the import :)

Comment: Yeah, it works now! Thank you! What's the difference between flatMap and switchMap ?

Comment: @AJT82 Are you able to help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68169715/mat-autocomplete-error-when-using-formarray